# How to create a list of generic case classes in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics

In my web app, a user uploads different kinds of data to our server: string, excel files, ints. I want to assemble all this data in one list if possible:

```
object CacheII extends App{
  case class Data[TypeT](kind: String, data: TypeT)

  val item1 = Data("type1", "data1")
  val item2 = Data("type1", "data2")
  val item3 = Data("type2", "data1".getBytes())
  val item4 = Data("type2", "data2".getBytes())

  val list = List(item1, item2, item3, item4)

  val item5 = if(true)
    Data("type2", "data1".getBytes())
  else if(true)
    Data("type1", "data1")
  else
    Data("type3", 548)

  def addItem(list: List[Data[Any]], item: Data[Any]) = {
    list :+ item
  }

  println(addItem(list, item5))
}
```

Compiler Error:

```
Error:(22, 19) type mismatch;
 found   : List[CacheII.Data[_ >: Array[Byte] with String <: java.io.Serializable]]
 required: List[CacheII.Data[Any]]
  println(addItem(list, item5))
                  ^
```

How to correctly create such a list of the user data?
Is there a different/better way to do this?

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You ask: "How to create a list of generic case classes in Scala?" However, that doesn't make sense: classes aren't objects in Scala, so you can't create a list of classes. Do you mean a list of `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` instances, i.e. reflective mirrors for classes / types?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I wanted to combine different kinds of data: bytes, string etc. in one list. I was trying to implement that using generics. That was what I needed help with since I couldnt get it to compile. One of the answer below suggests a  extending a trait which seems like a simpler solution. I do apologize for an unclear title.

Comment: So, you were asking about a list of *instances* of classes, not about a list of classes?

Comment: Yes. I guess I should have said generic instances of classes and not just classes. That was a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list using covariant `TypeT`. But general way to approach this problem is using ADTs

```
sealed trait Data

case class StringData(value: String) extends Data

case class ByteData(value: Array[Byte]) extends Data
```

and so on ....

#### Benefits

1. Pattern matching extraction.
2. Compiler error/warning when certain case is missed.
3. Less error prone
4. Auto complete support to generate all cases from IntelliJ idea and other IDEs
5. Elegant

#### Scala REPL

Adding different new data items to old list

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

    sealed trait Data

    case class StringData(value: String) extends Data

    case class ByteData(value: Array[Byte]) extends Data

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Data
defined class StringData
defined class ByteData

scala> val oldList = List(StringData("stackoverflow"), ByteData("scala".getBytes))
oldList: List[Product with Serializable with Data] = List(StringData(stackoverflow), ByteData([B@108b121f))

scala> def addItem(oldList: List[Data], newItem: Data): List[Data] = oldList ++ List(newItem)
addItem: (oldList: List[Data], newItem: Data)List[Data]

scala> addItem(oldList, StringData("cow goes moo"))
res1: List[Data] = List(StringData(stackoverflow), ByteData([B@108b121f), StringData(cow goes moo))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make Data covariant:

```
case class Data[+TypeT](kind: String, data: TypeT)
```

You can read more about variances at https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html